# Why does CMake export() command defer the output file creation? Can it be avoided?

Tags: cmake

We are including separate repositories into a common CMake superproject (which simply `add_subdirectory()` each repository folder, in the correct dependency order).

The different repositories all rely on [export()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html) to ouptut a `XxxTargets.cmake` file, such as:

```
# Assumes this repository provide the 'Alpha' target
install(TARGETS Alpha EXPORT AlphaTargets)

export(EXPORT $AlphaTargets
       FILE $AlphaTargets.cmake
       NAMESPACE myrepo::)
```

Yet, this superproject approach allowed us to observe that the **`export` does not create the file directly**. We could draw this conclusion because when the generated file is `include()` from another repository (added later, with a subsequent `add_subdirectory()`), the file does not exist yet.

- Why is `export()` delaying the file creation?
- And more importantly, is there a way to force it to actually create the file before the next `add_subdirectory()`?

Answer (score 2):

> - Why is `export()` delaying the file creation?

Because you are asking it to generate code for a particular export set, which isn't fully defined until the configure step ends. If it generated it immediately, then the behavior of `export()` and `install(EXPORT)` would be vexing and inconsistent.

> - And more importantly, is there a way to force it to actually create the file before the next `add_subdirectory()`?

The `export(TARGETS)` signature runs immediately as far as I know. But I also can't think of a single reason why you would need the generated exports file when working with `add_subdirectory`. The targets already exist, so there's no need to import them! If the names are different, create ALIAS targets as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, as far as I could observe even the `export(TARGETS)` form does not generate the file instantly (even though it now gives me an error which pretends it did, but there is no file at the path provided by the error). Anyway, the error is along the lines of `The file .../AlphaTargets.cmake was generated by the export() command.  It may not be used as the argument to the include() command.`, so this will not solve our specific problem.

Comment: As for the reason:
essentially, we are trying to use [Conan Workspaces](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/workspaces.html) on independent recipes (i.e. independent repos).
This means that CMake trees that are normally totally independent (hence the need to generate an export file to make a proper CMake package), but we would like to optionally use them in Conan Workspaces, which assemble the different repository under a common CMake tree (and the find_package() calls are still there, [since they cannot be disabled](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17735)).

Comment: You can disable a find_package call by writing out a dummy FindPkg.cmake

Comment: Thank you, that is what we are ending up doing, even though it feels a bit hackish (to have to write this dummy package config on the filesystem, then to write its path to `Pkg_DIR` variable when the targets are in the current build tree). Well, it will not be the first hackish code in our CMake scripts. Hoping one day there will be a standard CMake approach to disable `find_package()`!

Comment: @AdN - "Hoping one day there will be a standard CMake approach to disable find_package()!"... same here!